# Redirect domain with a query string to another domain?

Tags: domain, .htaccess, redirect, godaddy, querystring

I need to redirect a domain that does not have any content to another domain that is working. I have GoDaddy hosting.

- Domain 1: www.example-one.net: No content, just the domain.
- Domain 2: www.example-two.com: Working website.

I want `www.example-one.net/index.php/?query=value` to redirect to `www.example-two.com/value`

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Are both domains on the same account / pointing to the same place on the file system?

Comment: yes. both domain are on same account. i don't know how to point domain.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for the same. hope you are getting my requirment

Comment: There is nothing wrong in text typo. please don't edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> www.domain1.com/index.php/?query=value
> ```

In the `.htaccess` file in the document root, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.domain1.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.domain2.com/%1 [R=302,L]
```

This assumes that `value` consists of just "word" characters (ie. A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _). Also, `query=` must appear at the start of the query string (as in your example).

This is also a `302` (temporary) redirect. You should probably change this to `301` (premanent) when you are sure it's working OK. 301s are cached by the browser, so can make testing problematic.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.
But this solution is for single domain redirect. My hosting have two domain. Among them , one domain has content i.e. one can see website and other domain has no content for now i.e. one can not see website.